# Prove/disprove: Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. If $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n$ converges $\implies$ $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \max\{a_n, {1 \over n^2}\}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

**So I think this correct and have made an attempt to prove it and I would like to know if it is okay:**

Let $\{c_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ s.t $\forall n \in \mathbb {N}: \; c_n =  \max\{a_n, {1 \over n^2}\}$.

Notice $\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_n \leq \sum_{i=0}^\infty (a_n+{1 \over n^2}) \leq \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n + \sum_{i=0}^\infty {1 \over n^2}$.

From arthmetics of columns we have $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (a_n+{1 \over n^2})$ converges.

Therefore we have $\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_n$ converges as needed.

**Edit:**

So as explained in the comments my mistake was assuming $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n$ converges $\iff \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely. As written in the comment section by @Sangchul Lee, using $a_n = {(-1)^n \over n}$ would disprove the theorem.

Thanks to all!

Comment: Are $a_n$'s non-negative?

Comment: @geetha290krm that is not given. Must I use absolute value and absolute convergence maybe?

Comment: what does $c_n$ represent?

Comment: @Math-fun sorry just a typo

Comment: What if $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$?

Comment: @SangchulLee to the best of my knowledge a column converges $\iff$ it converges absolutely and for $a_n$ such as your example we have $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n = \sum_{i=0}^\infty {1 \over n}$ which is the harmonic column and does not converge. Or am I wrong?

Comment: What is a coloumn? I am sure most of us have never heard such a terminology

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron sorry the correct word is a series I'm sorry for the bad translation in my native language it translates differently.

Comment: I see. No issues. But what you state is incorrect. Convergence just means that the sequence of partial sums $s_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}$ converges to a finite real number. In particular $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k}$ **IS** convergent. Absolute convergence is a stronger property. Are you given that $\sum_{k}a_k$ is absolutely convergent?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron No that is not given. Ok, I see your point. This is my mistake for thinking absolute convergence is equal to regular convergence. Thank you!

Comment: Because if not. Then you cannot conclude the statement as Sangchul Lee points out. In his example. $\sum_{n}c_{n}=\frac{1}{1^{2}}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3^{2}}+\frac{1}{4}+...$ which does not converge. Specifically, $\sum_{n}c_{n}\geq \sum_{n}\frac{1}{2n}$ which is divergent. Unless you are given absolute convergence or some other conditions on $a_{n}$ , your statement will not in general be true. In that case, you go for a "disproof" and use Sangchul Lee's  comment as a counter example.

Comment: you can use ``\`` before max

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."